# Expected value for a function concerning a balls and bins problem

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

I'm optimizing a hash function mapping $M$ items into $N$ bins and I need a criterion for evaluating the quality of the mapping. Denoting the number of items put into bin $i$ by $x_i$, an ideal mapping would make each $x_i$ equal to either $\lfloor {\frac MN} \rfloor$ or $\lceil {\frac MN} \rceil$.

Currently, I'm using $\sum x_i ^ p$ with $p=3$ as my criterion. Are there simple closed form expressions for the *expected value* and *variance* assuming uniform random placement?

I might switch to another criterion, so I'm interested in formulas for them, too. I don't care about asymptotic expressions as the typical values are $10 < N < M < 1000$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry and linearity of expectation, the expected value is just $N$ times the expected value of $x_i^p$ for one bin, that is,

$$
N\sum_{k=0}^M\binom Mk\left(\frac1N\right)^k\left(1-\frac1N\right)^{M-k}k^3\;,
$$

which [according to Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%20binom%20%28m,k%29%20q%5Ek%20%281-q%29%5E%28m-k%29%20k%5E3%20for%20k=0..m%20where%20q=1/n) is

$$
\frac M{N^2}\left(M^2+3MN+N^2-3M-3N+2\right)\;.
$$

for $p=3$. You can calculate the variance similarly, by expressing it as an expectation value, but the resulting expression will probably be rather complicated.

If you want to use a different value of $p$, just replace it in the W|A input.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. Now it looks quite easy, but I couldn't hope to come to a usable expression in an acceptable time (and I didn't know that WA is that good).